# Run script when div is visible in browser window

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to run some JavaScript when a `div` is visible in the browser window, for example, when it is scrolled to, even repeatedly. How would I go about doing so?

Basic structure:

```
<div class='page1'></div>

<div class='page2'></div>

<div class='page3'></div>

<div class='page4'></div>
```

CSS:

```
div {
    float: left;
    height: 500px;
    width: 500px;
    margin: 50px 0;
    background: grey;
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Q5BUe/1/

Comment: get position of div, scrolled position of the window, window height and calculate whether or not it is within the boundaries.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10555998/change-css-element-with-jquery-when-scroll-reaches-an-anchor-point

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As with the other provided question/solution, here is the full implementation...

Upon loading, we run the function to assign the visible divs with the corresponding color.  On jQuery scroll handler, we continue to call the function to assign the new background color.

http://jsfiddle.net/Q5BUe/5/

```
$(allInView);
$(window).scroll(allInView);


function isScrolledIntoView(elem) {
    var docViewTop = $(window).scrollTop();
    var docViewBottom = docViewTop + $(window).height();

    var elemTop = $(elem).offset().top;
    var elemBottom = elemTop + $(elem).height();

    return ((elemBottom <= docViewBottom) && (elemTop >= docViewTop));
}

function allInView() {

    if (isScrolledIntoView($(".page1"))) $(".page1").css("backgroundColor", "red");
    else $(".page1").css("backgroundColor", "grey");

    if (isScrolledIntoView($(".page2"))) $(".page2").css("backgroundColor", "green");
    else $(".page2").css("backgroundColor", "#333");

    if (isScrolledIntoView($(".page3"))) $(".page3").css("backgroundColor", "yellow");
    else $(".page3").css("backgroundColor", "#222");

    if (isScrolledIntoView($(".page4"))) $(".page4").css("backgroundColor", "blue");
    else $(".page4").css("backgroundColor", "#111");

}
```

Answer (score 5):

Since your implying your using jQuery you could be like

```
if($('#element').is(':visible'))
{
    //do your thing
}
```