# Javascript-Event: Start it when visible in Browser-Window?

Tags: javascript, css

i iam looking for a solution for a Problem like this:

[Run script when div is visible in browser window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12322833/run-script-when-div-is-visible-in-browser-window)

My problem is: My DIV are stacked! You maybe know a solution?

---

EDIT:

I did try it like this: And it works! ... more or less :)

My Problem at the moment:

- If loadcontent() loads fast = it works!
- If it loads slow it doesn't!

Is there some way to solve this?

```js
function checkContentLoad(divId){
  
  if (divId == 'faq')
      { if($('#contentbox-faq').is(':visible'))
      { loadcontent('faq', '0', '0');
      }}
      
  if (divId == 'kontakt')
      { if($('#contentbox-kontakt').is(':visible'))
      { loadcontent('kontakt', '0', '0');
      }}
}
```

```html
<div id="contentbox-faq" class="contentbox-faq">

<script>
checkContentLoad('faq');
</script>

</div>
```

Comment: Show some code maybe??

Comment: possible duplicate of [Run script when div is visible in browser window](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12322833/run-script-when-div-is-visible-in-browser-window)

Comment: Hi Psylogic, i just added the code i have until now.

Comment: Have you try `promise` in `loadcontent` to load content and show loader until all data load so that user not able to scroll.