# Make numbers animate when user scrolls and reach a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-animate, counter

I have a simple jQuery code that works perfectly (and I would like to keep). The problem is that this animation is in a section below on page and it starts running when the page loads. I need this animation (numbers start at 0 and run until the number I put in the divs) to happen only when the user scroll and reaches that div. I searched on google and here on StackOverflow but the solutions that I found didn't work or required a plugin (which I don't wanna use).

Here's the Demo code that I have until the moment:
https://jsfiddle.net/aj7Lk2bw/2/

the jQuery is:

```
    $('.value').each(function () {
    $(this).prop('Counter',0).animate({
        Counter: $(this).text()
    }, {
        duration: 4000,
        easing: 'swing',
        step: function (now) {
            $(this).text(Math.ceil(now));
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: I suppose you need onscroll event and check some positions. If your elements appear in `window` - you can fire countdown.

Comment: A question to look https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3045852/triggering-jquery-event-when-an-element-appears-on-screen

Answer (score 9, accepted):

See if this is what you want: https://jsfiddle.net/aj7Lk2bw/19/

```
$(window).scroll(testScroll);
var viewed = false;

function isScrolledIntoView(elem) {
    var docViewTop = $(window).scrollTop();
    var docViewBottom = docViewTop + $(window).height();

    var elemTop = $(elem).offset().top;
    var elemBottom = elemTop + $(elem).height();

    return ((elemBottom <= docViewBottom) && (elemTop >= docViewTop));
}

function testScroll() {
  if (isScrolledIntoView($(".numbers")) && !viewed) {
      viewed = true;
      $('.value').each(function () {
      $(this).prop('Counter',0).animate({
          Counter: $(this).text()
      }, {
          duration: 4000,
          easing: 'swing',
          step: function (now) {
              $(this).text(Math.ceil(now));
          }
      });
    });
  }
}
```

Found the way to do it here: [Run script when div is visible in browser window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12322833/run-script-when-div-is-visible-in-browser-window)

Comment: Hi ! this is almost the perfect one. The only problem is that the numbers after counting up, they start to count backward to 1 hehe. I need the numbers to start counting from 0 until the desired value and stop at this value.

Comment: Hi Ze Claudio! Your solution works perfectly, thank you really much and sorry the delay to answer you back.

Answer (score 4):

This is a possible solution:

```
var section = document.querySelector('.numbers');
var hasEntered = false;

window.addEventListener('scroll', (e) => {
    var shouldAnimate = (window.scrollY + window.innerHeight) >= section.offsetTop;

    if (shouldAnimate && !hasEntered) {
    hasEntered = true;

    $('.value').each(function () {
        $(this).prop('Counter',0).animate({
        Counter: $(this).text()
        }, {
        duration: 4000,
        easing: 'swing',
        step: function (now) {
            $(this).text(Math.ceil(now));
        }
        });
    });

  }
});
```

the variable `section` is your blue section with the numbers, `hasEntered` is to not repeat the animation.

If the window scroll is higher than the section position, than it will animate!

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/aj7Lk2bw/18/

Answer (score 0):

Here I can share another example.

You can try that HTML:

```js
$(window).scroll(testScroll);
var viewed = false;

function isScrolledIntoView(elem) {
    var docViewTop = $(window).scrollTop();
    var docViewBottom = docViewTop + $(window).height();

    var elemTop = $(elem).offset().top;
    var elemBottom = elemTop + $(elem).height();

    return ((elemBottom <= docViewBottom) && (elemTop >= docViewTop));
}

function testScroll() {
  if (isScrolledIntoView($(".number")) && !viewed) {
      viewed = true;
      $('.value').each(function () {
      $(this).prop('Counter',0).animate({
          Counter: $(this).text()
      }, {
          duration: 4000,
          easing: 'swing',
          step: function (now) {
              $(this).text(Math.ceil(now));
          }
      });
    });
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="number">
                    
                             <div class="value-wrap">
                    <div class="value" akhi="">51</div>
                    <h4>YEARS IN BUSINESS</h4>
                </div>
               
                             <div class="value-wrap">
                    <div class="value" akhi="">29</div>
                    <h4>WORLDWIDE CERTIFICATION</h4>
                </div>
               
                             <div class="value-wrap">
                    <div class="value" akhi="">58</div>
                    <h4>COUNTRIES REPRESENTED</h4>
                </div>
               
                             <div class="value-wrap">
                    <div class="value" akhi="">6</div>
                    <h4>CONTINENT REPRESENTED</h4>
                </div>
  </div>
```