# How could jQuery change contextmenu style when scrolling on webpage?

Tags: jquery, contextmenu

When I scroll down in [this page](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/base-css.html), the left-side context menu switches its style simultaneously. How could I achieve this effect using jQuery?

Comment: Thats probabaly done using `scroll()` event .ref:http://api.jquery.com/scroll/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var t = $("#anchor-point").offset().top;

 $(document).scroll(function(){
   if($(this).scrollTop() > t)
   {   
      $('#voice2').css({"border-bottom":"2px solid #f4f5f8"});
      $('#voice3').css({"border-bottom":"2px solid #2e375b"});
   }
 });
```

[REFERENCE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10555998/change-css-element-with-jquery-when-scroll-reaches-an-anchor-point)

Happy Coding :)