# Change opacity of DIV when page scroll reaches an anchor

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've tried searching but couldn't find an answer. Tried this solution: [Change CSS element with JQuery when scroll reaches an anchor point](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10555998/change-css-element-with-jquery-when-scroll-reaches-an-anchor-point) But doesn't seem to work?

Basically when user scrolls down, and an an anchor point comes into view, to have a DIV under that anchor point begin to change opacity from 0 -> 1

I was trying it in Jsfiddle but it only starts changing opacity once you scroll way past the DIV, not the anchor, not sure what I'm doing wrong

http://www.jsfiddle.net/c4ut7om9/2/

```js
var t = $("#trigger").offset().top;

$(document).scroll(function(){
    if($(this).scrollTop() > t)
    {   
   $("#superclass").animate({'opacity':'1'},5500);
    }
});
```

```css
DIV
{ 
    margin:50px; 
    padding:50px; 
    background-color:lightgreen; 
}

#superclass
{ 
    margin:50px; 
    padding:50px; 
    background-color:red; 
    height:300px;width:300px;
    opacity:0;
}
```

```html
    <div>Hello</div>
    <div>Hello</div>
    <div>Hello</div>
    <div>Hello</div>
    <div>Hello</div>
    <div>Hello</div>
    <a id="trigger">TRIGGER - once this is in view, the red div should begin changing opacity from 0 to 1 </a>
    <div id="superclass">RED DIV</div>
    <div>Hello</div>    <div>Hello</div>    <div>Hello</div>
```

Thanks!

Comment: You need to add window height to scrollTop value first and then check if its greater than t

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were retrieving the current position of the *top* of the document, therefore your animation wouldn't be triggered until you are scrolling past the `#trigger` element.

You need to add the height of the `window` to the top position of the document and compare that value to the position of the `#trigger` element.

Your conditional statement would therefore be:

```
if ($(window).height() + $(this).scrollTop() > $("#trigger").offset().top) {
    // ...
}
```

[**Updated Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/0ayfmuLk/)

```
var t = $("#trigger").offset().top;

$(document).scroll(function () {
    if ($(window).height() + $(this).scrollTop() > t) {
        $("#superclass").animate({
            'opacity': '1'
        }, 5500);
    }
});
```