# How to make different css attributes change on multiple elements at the same time with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have this code to made the header and an img in the header to shrink when scrolling down.  It works fine except it's really jumpy as one css attribute changes before the other.  Is there a way to make both change at the same time?

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > 0){  
        $('#section-header-0').css({
           'line-height' : '44px'
        });

        $('#logo').css({
           'width' : '200px'
        });
    }
    else{
        $('#section-header-0').css({
           'line-height' : '96px'
        });

        $('#logo').css({
           'width' : '394px'
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Add a class to a container element and list your css rules under that class for those elements in the css. If your elements are top level elements, then add the class to body

Comment: They should all change at the same time. Changes to the DOM don't become visible until the function returns, and then the browser performs all updates.

Comment: Example somewhere would be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > 0){  
        $('#section-header-0').css({
           'line-height' : '44px'
        },{ duration: 200, queue: false });

        $('#logo').css({
           'width' : '200px'
        },{ duration: 200, queue: false });
    }
    else{
        $('#section-header-0').css({
           'line-height' : '96px'
        },{ duration: 200, queue: false });

        $('#logo').css({
           'width' : '394px'
        },{ duration: 200, queue: false });
    }
});
```

i hope the above helps you the queue: false basically tells them to run at once and not in a line, or queue

Answer (score -1):

Hello please try this link for a good idea to your solution.

[Change CSS element with JQuery when scroll reaches an anchor point](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10555998/change-css-element-with-jquery-when-scroll-reaches-an-anchor-point)

Copied from the link.

```
var t = $("#anchor-point").offset().top;

$(document).scroll(function(){
    if($(this).scrollTop() > t)
    {   
        $('#voice2').css({"border-bottom":"2px solid #f4f5f8"});
        $('#voice3').css({"border-bottom":"2px solid #2e375b"});
    }
});
```

Hope this helps

Comment: You should copy the main points from that link to your answer as currently this is a link-only answer and will probably get deleted. If this links dies in the future then your answer will be useless for people who are reading it

Comment: Link-only answers are no bueno (link might go dead and invalidate your answer). Please consider pulling relevant quotes or examples from the article