# Change CSS of body when scroll reach an anchor point with Jquery

Tags: jquery, html, scroll, anchor, slide

I seen this topic : [Change CSS element with JQuery when scroll reaches an anchor point](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10555998/change-css-element-with-jquery-when-scroll-reaches-an-anchor-point)

But it doesn't work with my fullscreen slides.

HTML

```
<body> 
      <div id="slide1"></div>
      <div id="slide2"></div>
      <div id="slide3"></div> 
</body>
```

CSS

```
#slide1, #slide2, #slide3 { height:100%; width: 100%; }
```

Comment: Please provide your code so we can see what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

This should do it for you, https://jsfiddle.net/ezj1Lfbw/6/

HTML

```
<body> 
      <div id="slide1"></div>
      <div id="slide2"></div>
      <div id="slide3"></div>
      <a id="trigger">trigger here</a>
</body>
```

JQuery

```
<script>
var t = $("#trigger").offset().top;

$(document).scroll(function () {
    if ($(window).height() + $(this).scrollTop() > t) {
                $("body").addClass("red");
    }
});
</script>
```

CSS

```
#slide1, #slide2, #slide3 { height:100vh; width: 80%; margin-left: 10%;}
#slide1{background: lightblue;}
#slide2{background: lightpink;}
#slide3{background: lightgreen;}
.red{background: red;}
```

Comment: It doesn't work, when I put a console.log() in it, anything appears in the console.

Comment: @PauleAnne did you open the fiddle? did the background change to red when you scrolled to the bottom?