# Multiple menu anchor links highlight while scrolling

Tags: jquery, scroll, menu, jquery-selectors, anchor

I have a one-page website with some anchor links as `li's` in a `ul`, I also have two menus that include the same anchor links.

The menu's look like:

```
<div id="nav">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#home" class="current_page_item" onclick="closeNav();">Home<li>
        <li><a href="#about" onclick="closeNav();">About<li>
        <li><a href="#faq" onclick="closeNav();">FAQ<li>
        <li><a href="#contact" onclick="closeNav();">Contact<li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I found some code that allows me to highlight the current anchor link from both of those menus (which is working):

```
const navsStr = '#nav li, #foot li';

$(navsStr).on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    const href = $(this).find('a').attr('href');
    let items = $(navsStr).find("a[href$='" + href + "']");

    $(items).parent().addClass('current_page_item').siblings().removeClass('current_page_item');  
});
```

What I'd also like to do is highlight those anchor links as the user scrolls down the page, I added the following code to my footer js, but it doesn't seem to work. My guess is that the new code is conflicting with my existing code I'm already using to highlight the navigation items, but even if I takeout that code, the scroll highlight code doesn't work. The code is working on another site, but I'm not trying to use multiple menus, so I think I'm doing something wrong.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var $sections = $('#nav, #overlay');

    $(window).scroll(function(){
        var currentScroll = $(this).scrollTop();
        var $currentSection

        $sections.each(function(){
            var divPosition = $(this).offset().top;

            if( divPosition - 1 < currentScroll ){
                $currentSection = $(this);
            }

            var id = $currentSection.attr('id');
            $('a').removeClass('current_page_item');
            $("[href=#"+id+"]").addClass('current_page_item');
        })
    });
});
```

Comment: What is not working? Is it not highlighting at all, or highlighting multiple links?

Comment: @BYates: When I click an anchor, the correct anchor highlights in both menus, but when I scroll nothing changes in either menu. The anchor I clicked on stays highlighted even if I scroll up and down the page. It's as if the new code isn't even there! Doesn't seem to be doing anything

Comment: It might help if you posted the code for the sections of the `body`. I'm wondering if your body sections have the same `id` attributes as your menus? Because you cannot repeat `id` values on the same page...

Comment: @BYates you are correct, I am repeating the body section ID's, I knew about not repeating ID's, but didn't think page ID's and anchor links were considered the same - although now that I write this, that sounds weird - not sure why I thought that.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is exactly what you are looking for, but to highlight you can change the CSS class on scroll by adding the new class and removing the old class with JQuery, or toggling the classes. So set a class such as "green" on all your  tags, then:

JQuery Add/Remove:

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
      $('.green').addClass('red');
      $('.green').removeClass('green');      
    });
```

Or Toggle:

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
      $('.green').toggleClass('red');
     $('.green').toggleClass('green');
   });
```

If you need it to change only at a certain scroll point, you might try this thread, which shows how to do it with pixel values or by anchors:
[Change CSS element with JQuery when scroll reaches an anchor point](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10555998/change-css-element-with-jquery-when-scroll-reaches-an-anchor-point)

Comment: Also: I'm not sure what is going on with var $currentSection on the 5th line of your 3rd block of code. It's missing the semi-colon at the end of the line and doesn't seem to be getting a value. Hope that helps.