# How do I trigger jQuery when an anchor reaches the top of the viewport?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to trigger a jQuery function on a div when an anchor reaches the **top** of the viewport. 
There are a lot of posts on StackOverflow based on an element entering the viewport (i.e the **bottom** of the viewport) see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10556028/10084649) for example.

Is it possible to trigger jQuery for the `.nav-down` element when the anchor `#trigger` hits the top of the view port?

**HTML:**

```
<div class="spacer"></div>
<a href="#" id="trigger">ANCHOR</a>
<div class="nav-down"></div>
<div class="spacer"></div>
```

**jS:**

```
function scroll_style() {
   var window_top = $(window).scrollTop();
   var div_top = $('#trigger').offset().top;

   if (window_top > div_top){
      $('.nav-down').css("background","green");
   }
}

$(function() {
  $(window).scroll(scroll_style);
  scroll_style();
 });
```

This jS/jSFiddle doesn't work as intended, but it'll give an idea of the thought process I have:

https://jsfiddle.net/vanstone/s643m85b/14/

Can anyone assist me with getting this to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using the `getBoundingClientRect()` to get the position of `<a>` with respect to the viewport and then implement your logic.

In the below example, I am checking for `top < 10` to factor in the height of `<a>`

```js
function scroll_style() {
  if ($('#trigger')[0].getBoundingClientRect().top < 10) {
    $('.nav-down').css("background", "green");
  } else {
    $('.nav-down').css("background", "yellow");
  }
}

$(function() {
  $(window).scroll(scroll_style);
  scroll_style();
});
```

```css
.spacer {
  height: 700px;
  background: red;
}

.nav-down {
  height: 250px;
  width: 100%;
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="spacer"></div>
<a href="#" id="trigger">ANCHOR</a>
<div class="nav-down"></div>
<div class="spacer"></div>
```